# Javascript Drop Down List will goes up before I select

Tags: javascript

I've been using the below coding for adding items into my dropdownlist after receiving a command "ES" from a slave device:

```
    if (cmd == "ES") {
        var i;
        var cb;

        if (ret.substr(2, 2) == "04") cb = ObjByID('cbDeptStr');
        else cb = ObjByID('cbCntrStr');
        i = cb.length;
        while (i > 0) {
            cb.remove(1); // to remove all items which is already on the list.
            i--;
        }

        var oOption;
        var rows = ret.substr(4).split('|');
        var n;

        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; ++i) {
            n = rows[i].substr(0, 4);
            if (n.length != 4) break;
            oOption = document.createElement("option");
            cb.options.add(oOption, i);
            oOption.innerHTML = n;
            oOption.value = n;

        }
    }
```

The command comes with the items that I need to add into the drop down list. The slave device will send this command "ES" to me every time i press the drop down list so that it will add the items into the list.

Problem is, every time I press the drop down list, I can see the items which had been added in the list, but after a second, the drop down list will go back up. I don't have time to select the item on the list. What's wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to populate the dropdownlist each time it is pressed?

Comment: I want to update the list with what the slave device sent. The dropdownlist will drop down for a second and automatically goes back up before I select an item. What's wrong?

Comment: Do the values change each time ?

Comment: Yes. That's y I want to remove the items first before I add in new items. But the dropdownlist will drop down for a second and automatically goes back up before I select an item. What's wrong?

Comment: I think it is the normal behavior.  You may need to use another event to bind values to the list

Comment: What do you mean by bind value to the list? Any example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27142/discussion-between-slacker-and-coolguy)

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically select the dropdownlist with click()

```
$('#id').click();
```

Comment: Don't really understand this. Could you explain?

Comment: Nope. I use javascript only.

Comment: Then you have to find a way to programmatically click the dropdownlist with javascript and include that code after populating the list with new values