# Javascript Can I add items to drop down list only when I click it (onclick event)?

Tags: javascript

Can we add items onto the drop down list only when we click that drop down list? I've put an onclick event like below:

```
<select id="DeptStr" style="width: 114px" onchange="Call()" onclick = "GetDept()">
```

GetDept() is the function for adding items into the drop down list.

But my result is, everytime I click on the drop down list, it will list down the items for around 1 second only and the list goes back up. I have no time to select any of the item. Do you guys know why?

My GetDept() is something like below:

```
            cb=ObjByID('cbDeptStr');
            i=cb.length;
            while(i>0)
            { 
                cb.remove(1);
                i--;
            }
            var oOption;
            var rows = ret.substr(4).split('|');                
            var n;           

            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; ++i)
            {
                n=rows[i].substr(0,4);
                if (n.length!=4)
                    break;
                oOption = document.createElement("option");             
                cb.options.add(oOption,i);
                oOption.innerHTML=n;
                oOption.value=n;

            }
```

Comment: Where is your GetDept() function ?

Comment: [Didn't you ask this question already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696798/javascript-drop-down-list-will-goes-up-before-i-select)

Comment: Probably because you change the list after you click it so the browser refreshes the list and it goes back up.

Comment: I cant see any javascript here? How much did you try? Show us

Comment: So, we cannot prevent the drop down list from going back up?

Comment: onclick event on select combobox is not supported by all browsers

Comment: Any other ideas on how to do it? I just want the drop down list to update the item while I click the drop down list.

Comment: Option elements don't have any markup content, you should set the text property, not the innerHTML.

Comment: Have you considered using a multiple select element instead?

Comment: How do we use multiple element?

Answer (score 0):

> "everytime I click on the drop down list, it will list down the items
>   for around 1 second only and the list goes back up. I have no time to
>   select any of the item. Do you guys know why?"

It's because when you click on the drop-down the `onClick` handler is fired which is pulling the focus away from the `<select>` element. When it loses focus it hides the options.

Comment: So, we cannot prevent the drop down list from going backup? How do we bring the focus back to <select>?

Comment: @Coolguy Yes. Just use a different event instead of `onclick`

Comment: I cannot think of another event which does the same thing. Do you have some ideas? I just want the drop down list to update the item while I click the drop down list.